# How can I pass a type in generic parameter using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net

I take all the properties of `T` in `properties` by reflection and by iteration I check all of them whether it is a class or not. If it is a class then I send its type in generic parameter for making the following object : `var myOrm = new MyORM<type1>();` . But I get error for the line. Here is my code:

```
    var type = typeof(T);
    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if(property.PropertyType.IsClass)
        {
            Type type1 = property.GetType();
            var myOrm = new MyORM<type1>();
        }
    }
```

What's wrong here and how can I Create `myOrm` object ?

Comment: type1 is a variable not a value.  For example, `int i = 1;  new MyORM<i>` doesn't make sense.

Comment: What do you want to do with `myOrm` after you create it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MakeGenericType` and `Activator.CreateInstance` to create the object. Althought it's unclear what you propose to do with it once you have created it, as you cannot statically access any of its methods.

This code will fail if there is no default constructor, again you have not shown how you propose to deal with that.

```cs
var type = typeof(T);
var properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if(property.PropertyType.IsClass)
    {
        Type type1 = property.GetType();
        var myOrm = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyORM<>).MakeGenericType(type1));
    }
}
```